# Как разделить каждую строку на две части по определенному символу

Tags: python

Есть переводчик, но нужно сделать так, чтобы только после = в каждой строчке переводился текст.

```
from googletrans import *
translator = Translator()
zapros = input('Введите название файла с расширением (пр. example.lang): ')
file = open(zapros, 'r')
#Здесь код обрезания
result = translator.translate(file, src='en', dest='ru')
print(result1)
```

а вот и часть файлика для перевода

```
achievement.xu2.screen=Screen
achievement.xu2.screen.desc=For you viewing pleasure
achievement.xu2.solar.panel=Solar Panel
achievement.xu2.solar.panel.desc=The sun gives power to all!
achievement.xu2.speed.upgrade=Speed Upgrade
achievement.xu2.speed.upgrade.desc=Boosts speed of transfer nodes.
achievement.xu2.spotlight=Spotlight
achievement.xu2.spotlight.desc=Shine light across the world
achievement.xu2.stack.upgrade=Stack Upgrade
achievement.xu2.stack.upgrade.desc=Boosts amount pulled from transfer nodes.
achievement.xu2.sun.crystal=Sun Crystal
achievement.xu2.sun.crystal.desc=Light through walls
achievement.xu2.techtree.start=Tech-Tree Start
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После выполения этого кода в `lines` будет список значений после `=`:

```
with open(zapros) as file:
    lines = [line.rstrip().split('=')[1] for line in file]
```

Comment: IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: @killytuGAMING Видимо, там есть строка без `=`, поставьте в конец спискового сокращения проверку `if '=' in line`

Comment: спасибо! Всё работает, но как можно добавить ещё первую часть без перевода